# unable to run faye server while using private_pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts, faye, private-pub

I tried following along with this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub which implements basic realtime functionality using private_pub gem.

I used `rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` to start the faye server (thin server)
However, every time I go to localhost:3000, the faye server shuts down due to `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

The console in chrome gives this error

`Failed to load resource http://localhost:9292/faye.js`

So, how do I run the server?

Rails version 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: ["BUG segmentation fault" while working with private_pub gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118758/bug-segmentation-fault-while-working-with-private-pub-gem)

> Try a different ruby version/patch.
>
> If that fixes it, then it's probably a bug in 1.9.3p362. You should
>   probably submit a bug report so the core devs know about it, or, if
>   you're up for it, take a look at the source and try to patch it
>   yourself and submit that.

Answer (score 0):

Add thin server starting command in initializer, so every time thin and faye will get started once your application is started.

Try like this,

Thread.new do
  system("rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production")
end