# "BUG segmentation fault" while working with private_pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts, faye, private-pub

I was trying the code from this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub. I grabbed the code from github.
However, whenever, I try to send a message from that app, the faye server shuts down giving following error:

```
/home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:105: 
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [i686-linux]
```

(It also displays long control frame information and stack trace information)

(The rails server keeps running fine)

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Try a different ruby version/patch.

Comment: yeah, using 1.9.2 gets rid of that error.

Comment: Then it's probably a bug in 1.9.3p362.  I'd submit a report so the core devs know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a different ruby version/patch.

If that fixes it, then it's probably a bug in 1.9.3p362.  You should probably submit a bug report so the core devs know about it, or, if you're up for it, take a look at the source and try to patch it yourself and submit that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many people who are encountering segfaults with ruby-1.9.3-p362

Personally, I have also encountered this with rvm compiled ruby-1.9.3-p362

Switching back to ruby-1.9.3-p327 solves the problem.